# mozwebsocket packet structure

Tags: firefox, protocols, websocket

**What is the `MozWebSocket` firefox binary message client -> server packet structure?**

Sending `ArrayBuffer` (`0x01 0x00 0x01`). Really sent `0x88 0x82 0xE7 0xEB 0x20 0x30 0xE4 0x03`. First 2 bytes doesnt change on different sessions (id size?). 
Here is for example chrome binary message packet structure -

`0x82` - id

`0xYY` 1bit - is masked? 7bit - data length

`0xZZ oxZZ oxZZ oxZZ` - 4 byte mask

data (masked)

---

> Note: Firefox currently only supports sending strings.

**Seems like there is no way to send binary data using firefox?**

Comment: If you control both the client and server, you could consider base64 encoding your data.  This will convert your binary data into a string, allowing you to send it from Firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only Chrome currently supports sending binary object types. Firefox does not yet support sending binary types. However, Mozilla is working on [the issue](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=676439) so there should be support in a Firefox release soon.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the packet structure is identical to Chrome's (or any other browser's).  Looking at the data framing section of the [latest spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-hybi-thewebsocketprotocol-17#section-5.2) suggests that this is a connection close message:

0x88: The leading 8 shows that this is the final fragment of the message.  The trailing 8 is the opcode for a connection close frame.

0x82: The msb shows that the message contains a mask.  The remaining 7 bits give the length of data sent - 2 bytes in this case.

0xE7 0xEB 0x20 0x30: The mask used to decode the message.

0xE4 0x03: The message sent - (0xE4^0xE7) (0x03 ^ 0xEB) [ == 0xE7 0x0C I think]

Assuming you aren't closing the connection client side, you could check whether your version of Firefox supports sending binary messages.